# samba sharing nfs mounted folder and SELINUX

Tags: samba, nfs, selinux, samba4, nfsv4

- in RHEL 7.9, samba-4.10.16-19, nfs-utils-1.3.0,
- server A and server B both have SELINUX as enforcing
- from server A, the folder `/data` is NFS exported.
- on server B, `mount A:/data /data` successfully mounts as NFS v4.1.
- on server B if I samba share out `/data` which is nfs mounted, it cannot be accessed **until I do `setenforce 0` on server B**.
- on server A, `/data` has the `samba_share_t` label and will samba share out from server A.
- on server B where `/data` is nfs mounted, it has the `nfs_t` label and I am unable to get the `samba_share_t` label to be applied with an `semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/data(/.*)?"`

What are the do's and dont's regarding samba sharing folders, NFS, and SELINUX as I have described it?  I really want to be able to samba share out the nfs mounted folder from server B because that's where all the user accounts and permissions information resides, everyone has a user account on server B that creates data under `/data` but they do not have an account on server A where `/data` physically resides and I do not want to have to create user accounts on server A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding samba not working with an NFS mounted folder...

`getsebool -a | grep samba`

by default  **samba_share_nfs** is off.

doing an `setsebool -P samba_share_nfs on`

fixes that.  The `-P` is for persistence, otherwise it'll be off again after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a good idea to use Samba to share an NFS mount, so I can't recommend you do this. NFS uses nfsv4 acls and Samba doesn't.